# Nested Conditional in Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, nested

I'm building out a form where there are certain fields that are required but depending on previous choices in the form indicated by a data-validate="required;" attribute. I've got this working fine until I get to the nested conditional and then nothing happens.

I've set up each action to change the background color of the page just as a visual indicator that the jQuery is working so I don't need to inspect the code each time for data-validate attributes.

My full code is below - the non working code starts at the comment begin nested conditional where I am attempting to see if a particular check box is selected. When selected the class of that input changes from "collapsed" to having no class and a new series of fields appears.

```
{!--validation script--}
{if segment_2 =="request"}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{assets_url}js/livelyValidator_source.js"></script>
  <link href="{assets_url}css/lively-validator.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script type="text/javascript" >
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // check value of select.services_select
        // then add data-validate="required;" to required fields
        // if select changes remove from no longer required fields
        // and add to the new fields

        $('select#services_select').change(function() {
           // assign the value to a variable, so we can do a conditional check
           // set required attribute for sub forms
            var selectVal = $('select#services_select :selected').val();

            if(selectVal =="school") {
                // set school required fields here
                $('#school_services input[name="organization_name"], #school_services input[name="city"], #school_services input[name="state"], #school_services input[name="country"], #school_services select[name="district_schools"]').attr("data-validate", "required;");
                $('body').css('background-color', '#c1c1c1');

                // remove data-validate="required;" from other options
                $('#individual_services input, #district_services input').removeAttr("data-validate");

            }
            else if(selectVal =="district") {
                // set district required fields here
                $('#district_services input[name="organization_name"], #district_services input[name="city"], #district_services input[name="state"], #district_services input[name="country"], #district_services select[multiple="multiple"]').attr("data-validate", "required;");
                // body class is temporary just to prove that conditional is working
                $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');

                // remove data-validate="required;" from other options
                $('#individual_services input, #school_services input').removeAttr("data-validate");

            }
            else if(selectVal =="teacher") {
                // set teacher required fields here
                $('#individual_services input[name="mailing_city"], #individual_services input[name="mailing_state"], #individual_services input[name="mailing_country"]').attr("data-validate", "required;");
                // body class is temporary just to prove that conditional is working
                $('body').css('background-color', 'green');

                // remove data-validate="required;" from other options
                $('#district_services input, #school_services input').removeAttr("data-validate");



            //begin nested conditional to check teacher affiliation
                 $('input[name="affiliated"]').change(function() {
                   // assign the value to a variable, so we can do a conditional check
                    var affiliatedVal = $('input[name="affiliated"]:checked').val();

                   // set required attribute for sub fields                        

                    // set school required fields here

                    // this line should check if affiliatedVal does not have class collapsed but it doesn't work
                        if(!$(affiliatedVal).hasClass('collapsed')) { 
                        $('#school_info input[name="city"], #school_info input[name="state"], #school_info input[name="country"]').attr("data-validate", "required;");
                        $('body').css('background-color', 'pink');

                    }
                    else if(affiliatedVal =="district") {
                        // set district required fields here

                    }
                    else if(affiliatedVal =="organization") {
                        // set organization required fields here

                    }// end nested conditional
                });


            }// end outer conditional
        });

    });

    $(document).ready( function(){ $('#request-services').livelyValidator(); });
  </script>
{/if}
{!-- end validation script--}
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: 1) create a jsfiddle.net with rendered html. 2) use console.log to see what the value is

Answer (score 0):

Would bet the issue lays here

```
// this line should check if affiliatedVal does not have class collapsed but it doesn't work
if(!$(affiliatedVal).hasClass('collapsed')) {
```

affiliatedVal is a value(text), hence no selector to check hasClass with, use `affiliatedInput` in there and instead of

```
var affiliatedVal = $('input[name="affiliated"]:checked').val();
```

use

```
var affiliatedInput = $('input[name="affiliated"]:checked');
var affiliatedVal = affiliatedInput.val();
```

Comment: Basti,I just tried what you posted and it didn't change, still doesn't add the data-validate attribute.